# PostgreSQL Viewing a set of related records of the same table in a single row

Tags: postgresql

Let's have the following table thought to contain linked records:

```
CREATE TABLE tbl(id integer,
                 name text,
                 next_id integer,
                 UNIQUE(id),
                 FOREIGN KEY(next_id) REFERENCES tbl(id));
```

With the given data inserted in it:

```
INSERT INTO tbl(id,  name, next_id)
         VALUES( 1, 'x_0',       2),
               ( 2, 'x_1',       3),
               ( 3, 'x_2',    null),
               ( 4, 'y_0',       5),
               ( 5, 'y_1',       6),
               ( 6, 'y_2',       7),
               ( 7, 'y_3',    null);
```

We can self join this table in order to obtain each set of linked data viewed in single row:

```
SELECT
   *
FROM
   tbl t_1 LEFT JOIN tbl t_2 ON t_1.next_id = t_2.id
           LEFT JOIN tbl t_3 ON t_2.next_id = t_3.id
           LEFT JOIN tbl t_4 ON t_3.next_id = t_4.id
WHERE t_1.id = 1 OR t_1.id = 4
ORDER BY t_1.id ASC;
```

Now the question is:
How can be written a query allowing to achieve the same goal in general case,
when number of elements in linked sets and number of sets is arbitrary.
Many thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot write a query that produces an unknown number of columns. The structure of a query result is defined by that query. However, you can aggregate results in arrays. This could be done with a recursive query like this:

```
with recursive cte as (
    select
        id,
        next_id,
        array[id] as ids,
        array[name] as names
    from tbl t
    where not exists (
        select from tbl s
        where s.next_id = t.id)
union all
    select 
        c.id,
        t.next_id,
        ids || t.id,
        names || t.name
    from tbl t
    join cte c on c.next_id = t.id
)
select distinct on (id)
    id,
    ids,
    names
from cte
order by id, cardinality(ids) desc

 id |    ids    |       names
----+-----------+-------------------
  1 | {1,2,3}   | {x_0,x_1,x_2}
  4 | {4,5,6,7} | {y_0,y_1,y_2,y_3}
(2 rows)
```

[Db<>Fiddle.](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=82a30b375e242120147e9eaf51654876)

Read about recursive queries [in the documentation.](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-with.html)

Comment: Now thats neat!

Comment: Great! Thank you very much!